# How do I remove security certificate exceptions from Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, security, ssl, certificate

I am a developer and have created a certificate for my application.
The first time I access it Chrome states that the certificate is not recognized and suggests to leave the website.

There is however the option to add an exception, which I did, and the website becomes accessible.

Now I need to remove that exception, but I cannot find it any were in Chrome's settings. Chrome version is 45.0.2454.85 m

Comment: have you looked in `Settings` -> `Show advanced settings` -> `Manage certificates`?

Comment: Ok, I've found it. In the address bar, clicking on the lock next to the URL will show the certificate details. There is a button to stop using the certificate.

Comment: I'm trying to do this for a domain that has a redirect. I can't click the address bar because I'm immediately redirected elsewhere. Is there another way to remove the exception?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've finally found the answer.

On the address bar, click on the padlock to show the certificate details.
In the *Connection* tab there is a button "Stop using this certificate". Click it to remove the exception.

[image]

Comment: This probably works, but what if the URL causes a 302/301, so you never stay at its location for long enough to do this?

Answer (score 9):

Chrome looks a little different these days, so here's an updated picture of where to re-enable the warnings.

You still begin by clicking the "Not secure" indicator to the left of the URL.  Then, in the panel that pops up, you click the "Re-enable warnings" link.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

01/2017 - After many Chrome updates, now you just click to the left of the URL, where the padlock is, or if something else (mine is a local server, displaying a "red triangle Not secure"), click that to display the information about the connection, then click "Re-enable warnings"

Comment: Which is basically what explained in my answer ;)

Answer (score 6):

To "Re-enable warnings" for all SSL warnings if you don't want to clear your history (or if you dont know all the exemptions you have in place), you can close Chrome and edit: 
   `"C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences"`
and set     `ssl_cert_decisions":{},"`

Stored in the JSON-path:

> profile > content_settings > exceptions > ssl_cert_decisions

Or you can change the decision_expiration_time of the specific exemption to be equal to the last_modified time

Example:    `"ssl_cert_decisions":{"https://expired.badssl.com:443,*":{"last_modified":"13235055329485008","setting":{"cert_exceptions_map":{"-201cgaDTf2DD6Cj0N6/tKvudkzDuRBA3GwKd8T9hE7mHhQ=":1},"decision_expiration_time":"13235055329485008","version":1}}}`

Comment: There is nothing in C:\Users\{My User Id}... it's an empty directory!

Comment: This is a great answer. It wipes all of the exceptions without requiring you to know what exceptions you've added or have the sites you've added exceptions for accessible or in the blocked site list.

I'm surprised this isn't exposed in the chrome settings. @Michael do you have anything at `%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Deafult\Preferences`?

Answer (score 4):

In case the HTTPS URL triggers a 301/302 redirection to an HTTP URL, the methods described above won't work since the browser immediately redirects to a non-secure page which doesn't include the padlock button (as pointed out by Alex in the comments).

In this case, it's possible to work around this problem by disabling redirections for the website:
`Settings` -> `Advanced` -> `Site Settings` -> `Pop ups and redirects` -> `Block` -> `Add` -> Add the URL -> Visit the URL -> Disable the exception according to the accepted answer -> Remove redirection block.

Comment: it looks that it doesn't work anymore - there is some issue in Google Chrome